# Harvard referencing in Word 2007?

Tags: microsoft-word, reference-book

In the References area of the ribbon it has APA and other styles, but I need to use Harvard convention.

Is there any way for Word to generate and manage this for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This blogger](http://davidburela.wordpress.com/2007/05/03/harvard-style-referencing-in-office-20007/) dug up [exactly what you're looking for](http://www.codeplex.com/bibliography/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=15852). It also seems to include citation format for IEEE as well.

Comment: Wow, thanks Darth.

It has a few different Harvards there: Anglia, Exeter and Leeds.

The plot thickens...

Comment: Glad to help. Hopefully the IEEE is useful, because the other one I tried a while back was horrible. I'll have to remember to use this one next time I need to write a paper.

Answer (score 1):

It's one that is asked often by my students. Part of me says, do it yourself manually. And the other says take a short cut. Basically there's a number of different add ons. The one I use is called bibword which you can place it safely in your Word 2007 directories.

There are also some useful online tools such as Neil's Toolbox which might help. As your respondent above says, some people use EndNote but I am not familiar with it.

My academic writing site is [here](http://www.harvardreferencingword.com) if you want to have a look.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an overview from [Wikipedia on reference managers that support Harvard style.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_reference_management_software#Citation_styles)

Personally I have only used EndNote and it worked fine. It uses [plugins to support several styles](http://www.endnote.com/support/enstyles.asp), though I assume Harvard will be in there by default.

Here's even [a direct link](http://www.endnote.com/support/enstyledetail.asp?SORT=2&PAGE=1&METH=0&DISC=none&JOUR=none&BSRT=none&FF1=none&FF2=none&FF3=none&CITE=none&DKEY=64201050502OAA) to the Harvard one.

Example screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Hmm, I was hoping that I could of used something out of the box within Word.  Some are just ISO codes, which aren't particular helpful! :-) hehe

Comment: Thanks though, I might give one of those (free) ones a try!

Comment: Trust me, if you have to write something with more than 30 references, you'll regret not using something more advanced. And it will probably save you a lot of time. And time is money!